# Ionic : background cover on ion slide doesn't work when deployed

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I've a problem on my app with my backgrounds. On my screen when deployed my css property "background-size: cover" won't work and images are resized like if it was translated to "width:100%; height: 100%". Any solution ?

My scss code :

```
page-home {
  ion-slides {

    ion-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      padding-left: 40px;
      padding-right: 40px;
      min-width: 365px !important;
    }

    #slide1 {
      background-image: url('../assets/img/fond1_opacity50.jpg');
      background-position: left;
    }

    #slide2 {
      background-image: url('../assets/img/fond2_opacity50.jpg');
      background-position: left;
    }

    [...]
  }
}
```

My html code :

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides autoplay="3000" loop="true" speed="500">
    <ion-slide id="slide1">
      [...]
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide id="slide2">
      [...]
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

On phone vs on browser :

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the structure of your slides? I'd guess that `#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 {background-size: cover}` would sort you out without knowing any layout structure.

Comment: I've edited the first post with the html code :)

Comment: ah ok, depending on which phone that property may need a vendor prefix, like -webkit-background-size:

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried them but it still didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My background-image was to big (5000x4000px)

I've made a lot of tries and apparently the problem only occurs on some phone and not others : maybe the phone was too weak to process it and abandon sizing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  ion-content {
    background-size: cover;
  }

#slide1 {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/fond1_opacity50.jpg');
  background-position: left;
}
```

Comment: I have a different background for each one of my slides ... (I've edited the first post)

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe

```
 ion-content {
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }



  #slide1 {
     background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat left left fixed;

    }
```

Comment: It dorsn't work... How putting background-size on -ion-content can affect my slides background ?